# How do I create a dataframe from another dataframe with only the last non negative values for each value column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, multi-index

I have a multi-indexed dataframe like so:

```
           year  value   value2 value3   some_other_column_i_dont_care_about
  one two             
  a   t     2000     0     1     7        aaa
      w     2001     3    -1     4        bbb
      t     2002    -2     1     -3       ccc
  b   t     2000     4     3     6        ddd
      w     2001     7     5     -1       eee    
      t     2002    -8    -3     3        fff
  c   t     2000    11    10     3        ggg
      w     2001   -12    -9     -1       hhh
      t     2002   -15    -6     -5       iii
```

How do I create a new, single level df, that just has the latest (in terms of years) non-negative values, like so:

```
            value  value2 value3
 one    
 a            3      1     4
 b            7      5     3
 c           11     10     3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html#pandas-melt), use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas-dataframe-query) to keep `values >=0`, then use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas-pivot-table) with `aggfunc='last'` to get to wide format again:

```
new_df = (
    df.reset_index('one')
        .melt(id_vars='one',
              value_vars=['value', 'value2', 'value3'],
              value_name='values')
        .query('values >= 0')
        .pivot_table(index='one', columns='variable', aggfunc='last')
        .droplevel(0, axis=1)
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

Alternatively use [`groupby last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-last) to keep the last value from each group, then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas-dataframe-unstack) after `melt`:

```
new_df = (
    df.reset_index('one')
        .melt(id_vars='one',
              value_vars=['value', 'value2', 'value3'],
              value_name='values')
        .query('values >= 0')
        .groupby(['one', 'variable'])
        .last()
        .unstack()
        .droplevel(0, axis=1)
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

---

`new_df`:

```
   value  value2  value3
a      3       1       4
b      7       5       3
c     11      10       3
```

---

Assuming years are not guaranteed to be in ascending order chain [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values) before melt:

```
new_df = (
    df.reset_index('one')
        .sort_values('year')  # Sort By Year
        .melt(id_vars='one',
              value_vars=['value', 'value2', 'value3'],
              value_name='values')
        .query('values >= 0')
        .pivot_table(index='one', columns='variable', aggfunc='last')
        .droplevel(0, axis=1)
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'one': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
    'two': ['t', 'w', 't', 't', 'w', 't', 't', 'w', 't'],
    'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2001, 2002],
    'value': [0, 3, -2, 4, 7, -8, 11, -12, -15],
    'value2': [1, -1, 1, 3, 5, -3, 10, -9, -6],
    'value3': [3, 4, -3, -1, 3, -2, 7, -9, 3],
    'some_other_column_i_dont_care_about': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee',
                                            'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh', 'iii']
}).set_index(['one', 'two'])

new_df = (
    df.reset_index('one')
        .melt(id_vars='one',
              value_vars=['value', 'value2', 'value3'],
              value_name='values')
        .query('values >= 0')
        .pivot_table(index='one', columns='variable', aggfunc='last')
        .droplevel(0, axis=1)
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)

print(new_df)
```

Comment: Wonderful!  This solves it completely.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Stockmage I was looking at your profile and I notice you've never [accepted  an answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You are under no obligation to mark an answer as excepted, but it helps to notify others the problem has been solved. Please consider going through the questions which have been completely solved (as you say this one has) and clicking the checkmark to the left and/or up-voting it by clicking the up arrow in the same area. (See [What does it mean to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for information) Thanks!